# click n'th item in list e2e

Tags: angular, ionic2, e2e-testing

I am testing my app using protractor. I have a list of same class I need to click the 3rd button in that list.

```
<ion-content class="List">

    <button dark class="listItems" ion-item detail-none *ngFor="#order of orderList" (click)="orderSelected(order)">
        {{order.documentNo}}<br><br>
        {{order.rwsCustomer$_identifier}}
        <span item-right class="Rs">
            Rs {{order.grandTotalAmount}}
        </span>
        <span item-right>
            <ion-icon name="arrow-forward"></ion-icon>
        </span>
    </button>

</ion-content>
```

In my e2e, I wrote like this:

```
it('should go 3nd order detail page', () => {
         element.all(by.css('.listItems').get(2)).click();
    });
```

I get an err in my terminal like this:

```
e2e.ts (39,37): Property 'get' does not exist on type 'Locator'. (2339)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're applying `get` function to a locator. Just update your code to:

```
it('should go 3nd order detail page', () => {
    element.all(by.css('.listItems')).get(2).click();
});
```